# Проставить className для child React компонента

Tags: reactjs

есть сторонний компонент, который предоставляет текстовый input

```
import {TextField} from package;

const myForm = () => {

    return (
        <TextField name="name" .../>
    );
}
```

TextField в html представляет из себя div контейнер, который содержит в себе input. Что-то вроде того:

```
<div>
    <input name="name" id="id" value="">
</div>
```

Мне нужно проставить className для input, чтобы к нему применились нужные мне стили

проблема в том, что если я добавляю className для компонента TextField

```
<TextField name="name" className="classCss".../>
```

он применяется для внешнего div

```
<div class="classCss">
    <input name="name" id="id" value="">
</div>
```

а это мне не подходит

Насколько я понял, мне подойдет вариант перебрать всех child от этого компонента и заменить их на склонированные child с нужным классом

что-то типа:

```
<TextField ...>
    {
        this.props.children.map((el, index) => {
            return React.cloneElement(el, {
                key: index,
                className: el.className + " classCss"
            });
        })
    }
</TextField>
```

но я не могу понять, как получить доступ к child (и props) импортированного компонента

Comment: Вполне достаточно что класс будет у самого дива... Стилизовать инпут можно и таким селектором `.classCss input {/* тут стили */}`

Comment: Да вот хотелось лаконично сделать, чтобы не таскать и не поддерживать стили. Получается, нет никакого способа получить доступ к child импортированного компонента?

Comment: В чужом компоненте можно использовать только то что он предоставляет сам. Если какой-то возможностью компонент не предоставляет - значит ее нет для тебя.